# Is chaos-based cryptography quantum-resistant?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

Recently, I have been learning chaos-based cryptography. Is the Chebyshev map-based encryption algorithm quantum-resistant?

Comment: In general wherever you see the word "chaos" it is probably snakeoil.

Comment: But chaos based cryptography algorithms are already widely used I think, can you share your reason or your opinion on this?

Comment: Where is it widely used? Evidence? See this answer https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64723/explaining-chaotic-cryptography?

Comment: And this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64555/improving-efficiency-of-an-encryption-algorithm-based-on-a-chaotic-map?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thanks for the links kodlu, widely used I mean I have seen a large amount of literature on this topic,sorry about my poor english. But I indeed do not know that whether chaos based cryptography is publicly accepted in practical. So the reason of lacking rigorous proof is what? Complexity or something else?

Comment: The skepticism about "chaos-based crypto" is likely due to several frankly snake oil products which touted that they were based on chaos, leading us to automatically question anything that uses similar terminology.  In addition, we in crypto have an automatic bias to question anything novel; instead of asking for evidence that something is weak, we ask for evidence that something is strong before we consider trusting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient explanation poncho. So what you're saying is that we're skeptical, but at the same time we can't strictly say that chaos-based cryptography is not quantum-resistant, in my opinion, because we still do not understand chaos systems well enough right?

Comment: Well, there was a NIST PQ round 1 submission based on Chebyshev polynomials (RVB) - it was quickly broken (although I don't know whether the break was inherent to Chebyshev polynomials, or just that the specific cryptosystem was poorly chosen).

Comment: Really really thanks for your help poncho, you are knowledgeable and helpful.